# How do I get the slurpuff dress in pokemon x/y

Tags: pokemon-x-y

The girl always says she wants to see a girl in a colourful outfit but is there a specific outfit you gotta wear?

Comment: Your title and content are asking two different questions. Do you want to know what the "colourful outfit" is or do you want to know how to get the Slurpuff Dress?

Comment: I figured it out earlier, thanks though!

Comment: @Yuki: Wearing a colorful/feminine outfit is how you get the Slurpuff dress, so they're not that different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For female characters, you will need pale pink coloured clothes. You need to wear at least 3 accessories that are of the pale pink colour.

I tried with 2 pale pink accessories and everything else pink but it didn't work, whence my conclusion above.

I also tried 3 pale pink accessories, with everything else being another colour; black, grey, etc and still got the accessory.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, a lot of pink or pale pink should work. If that does not work try looking like a rainbow. (Every piece in a different color)